# Bootstrap analysis from a conditional logistic regression

Tags: r, bootstrap, cox-model, clogit

How can I perform a bootstrap analysis from a conditional logistic regression? The model has been built using the `clogit` function (`survival` package)? The model has the following structure:

```
mod <- clogit(event ~ forest + log_area +forest:log_time  + cluster(ID_individual)  +   strata(ID_strata), method = "efron", data = data , x=T, y=T)
```

Using bootstrapping, I would like to have a measure of uncertainty around the estimates of beta coefficients.

I am using the following code but I don't know how to consider strata and cluster arguments.

```
library(boot)
boot.clogit <- function(data, indices){
  new_data <- data[indices,] 
  mod <- clogit(event ~ forest + log_area + forest:log_time  + cluster(ID_individual)  +  strata(ID_strata),
                method = "efron", data = new_data, x=T, y=T)
  coefficients(mod)
}

boot_data <- boot(data=data, statistic=boot.clogit, R=5000)
```

Here is an overview of my data set:

[image]